# How to justify css table cells?

Tags: html, css

Well basically I have a css table that looks like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     First    |    Middle1    |    Middle2    |    Last    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm looking to get this design

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| First        |    Middle1    |    Middle2    |       Last |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

First column is aligned to left, middle columns are aligned to center, and last column is aligned to right. Currently I'm using a solution that targets :first-child and :last-child in order to align them specifically. Is there a better/smarter way?

Comment: Do you want to use Flexbox?

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: the html is just few divs that parent has display:table and child have display:table-cell. I tried to use flex box but it's still buggy and browsers calculated widths differently

Answer (score 4):

Align attributes are now deprecated. They still work in terms of aligning content but generally should not be used. Use CSS pseudo-element selectors to target the first and last cell in each row.

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}

tr td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

tr td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [td align](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp) attribute:

```css
td {
  min-width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">Left</td>
    <td align="center">Center</td>
    <td align="center">Center</td>
    <td align="right">Right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm using css table, but even if I was using a regular table, this solution still requires to target first and last child which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Just FYI there's no such thing as a "CSS Table." You can use CSS to make divs act like table cells, if that's what you mean. If that's the case you may want to reword your question as it will confuse people. Posting your HTML/CSS will probably help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS:

```
td {
  text-align: center;
}
td:nth-child(1)
{
  text-align: left;
}
td:nth-child(4)
{
  text-align: right;
}
```